# gcc, 64 bit, oracle, solaris

Tags: oracle, gcc, solaris, ld

```
info@s490up # gcc -std=gnu99 -o bla -g -O2 -DSunOS=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES= -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/u/app/oracle/product/11.2/rdbms/demo -I/u/app/oracle/product/11.2/rdbms/public -I/u/app/oracle/product/11.2/rdbms/demo -I/u/app/oracle/product/11.2/rdbms/public blabla.c -lclntsh -lrt -lresolv -lnsl -lsocket -lm -lpthread -liconv -L/usr/lib -R/usr/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -lm -lsocket -lnsl -L/u/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib
ld: fatal: file /u/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
ld: fatal: File processing errors. No output written to bla
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone give me an idea why `ld` does not work correctly here

(this long command has been taken from `configure` which is not performing right, because of this error)

**UPD**

```
file /u/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so
/u/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so:    ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped
```

The `blabla.c`:

```
info@s490up # cat /tmp/blabla.c
/* confdefs.h.  */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define GW_NAME "Kannel"
#define GW_VERSION "1.4.3"
#define VERSION "1.4.3"
#define YYTEXT_POINTER 1
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STRING_H 1
#define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
#define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
#define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define SIZEOF_SHORT 2
#define SIZEOF_INT 4
#define SIZEOF_LONG 4
#define SIZEOF_LONG_LONG 8
#define HAVE_LIBM 1
#define HAVE_LIBSOCKET 1
#define HAVE_LIBNSL 1
#define HAVE_LIBRESOLV 1
#define STDC_HEADERS 1
#define HAVE_SYS_IOCTL_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
#define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_POLL_H 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD_H 1
#define HAVE_GETOPT_H 1
#define HAVE_SYSLOG_H 1
#define HAVE_ICONV_H 1
#define HAVE_ZLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H 1
#define HAVE_SYS_SOCKIO_H 1
#define HAVE_NETINET_IN_H 1
#define HAVE_NET_IF_H 1
#define HAVE___FUNCTION__ 1
#define HAVE___FUNC__ 1
#define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
#define HAVE_SELECT 1
#define HAVE_SOCKET 1
#define HAVE_STRDUP 1
#define HAVE_GETOPT_LONG 1
#define HAVE_LOCALTIME_R 1
#define HAVE_GMTIME_R 1
#define HAVE_SRANDOM 1
#define HAVE_FUNC_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5 1
#define HAVE_SOCKLEN_T 1
#define HAVE_GETOPT_IN_STDIO_H 1
#define HAVE_REGEX_H 1
#define HAVE_REGEX 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD_SPINLOCK_T 1
#define HAVE_PTHREAD_RWLOCK 1
#define HAVE_LIBRT 1
#define HAVE_SEMAPHORE 1
#define SUFFIX ""
#define USE_GWMEM_NATIVE 1
#define LOG_TIMESTAMP_LOCALTIME 1
#define ENABLE_COOKIES 1
#define USE_KEEPALIVE 1
/* end confdefs.h.  */

/* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
   Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
   builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char OCIEnvCreate ();
int
main ()
{
return OCIEnvCreate ();
  ;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're mixing up 32-bits and 64-bits. What's the target triple of your gcc / default bitness? What do you get for `file /u/app/oracle/product/11.2/lib/libclntsh.so`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libclntsh.so` is a 64 bit binary library which you are linking with a 32bit code. Check to make sure you have the right library.

**Edit:**

> ELF 64-bit MSB dynamic lib SPARCV9
>   Version 1, dynamically linked, not
>   stripped

GCC 64-bit toolchain is having trouble linking against a library built on Sparc platform which  could mean either one of two things

- Endianess? One thing that is not clear, ***what platform are you running the gcc toolchain under?***
- Issue this command `gcc --version` and also run this command `file /usr/bin/gcc` to determine the executable's binary type. And compare the results with what's the library's binary type is...

Comment: i've added the `blabla` source. and seems like it is not 32bit, is it?

Comment: The source isn't 32-bit per-se - that depends on the compiler switches / compiler default. But it's got `#define SIZEOF_LONG 4` and 64-bit Linux has 8-byte longs (on x86/64 at least) so if it's autodetected that from your compiler then it is 32-bits, yes.

Comment: Hmmmm :-S those defines came from "checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 4"

Comment: I don't know what the best way to force 64-bit compile through configure is. You can try `export CC="gcc -m64"`, or maybe you could set it on the cflags e.g. `export CFLAGS="-m64 -O2 -g"` - assuming bash shell - you may need separate set / export if you're running the Sun ksh

Comment: `--with-cflags="-m64 -O2 -g"` did the trick! i've upvoted this answer, but @Rup i think that you gave more significant advice. So add another separated **comment** and I will check it with bounty.

Comment: @tommieb75: gcc is 32bit "/usr/local/bin/gcc:     ELF 32-bit MSB executable SPARC Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available"

Comment: and to be clear - even though i've get configure successfull - `gmake` has failed... but i'm in one step closer now ;-)

Comment: The gcc binary is 32-bit, but it can build 64-bit libraries and binaries. If you can't figure out how to get the -m64 flag to pass through into the Makefile that `configure` creates, and you're not particularly looking for a 64-bit build, you could try altering other environment variables so it picks up the 32-bit Oracle library instead; don't have an 11g version to check at the moment but earlier versions used to have an ORACLE_HOME/lib32 as well.